# hibernate 6.x.x does not have LimitHelper and RowSelection, has EmptyInterceptor marked deprecated, and its Dialect class has some methods deprecated

Tags: hibernate, maven, deprecated

My micro service uses hibernate 5 and have the following: org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.LimitHelper, org.hibernate.engine.spi.RowSelection, and org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor. We are trying to migrate to Hibernate 6, but all these components are gone (except the EmptyInterceptor which shows deprecated and cannot be used). Therefore, may I know if there are alternatives for those components in Hibernate 6? I tried to search in Hibernate 6 documentation (including deprecation documents) but there is no luck in finding the answer.

Some details:

1. For the RowSelection class, I am doing public String processSql(String sql, RowSelection selection),
2. For the LimitHelper class, I am using LimitHelper.hasFirstRow(selection) -- the selection here is the selection created above.
3. For the EmptyInterceptor() class, I am overriding the public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) method.
4. The org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect seems to no longer have the following methods: public boolean supportsLimit(), and public String getLimitString(String sql, boolean hasOffset). My class DruidDialectExtended() is extending from org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect. May I know what are my options?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: would you mind shed a light on how you were using those classes? At first glance that is enough to call `jakarta.persistence.Query#setMaxResults` and `jakarta.persistence.Query#setFirstResult`

Comment: Thanks Andrey! 

1. For the RowSelection class, I am doing public String processSql(String sql, RowSelection selection),
2. For the LimitHelper class, I am using LimitHelper.hasFirstRow(selection) -- the selection here is the selection created above.
3. For the EmptyInterceptor() class, I am overriding the public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) method.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Sorry forgot to mentioned one more thing: The org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect seems to no longer have the following methods: public boolean supportsLimit(), and public String getLimitString(String sql, boolean hasOffset). My class DruidDialectExtended() is extending from org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect. May I know what are my options?

Comment: well, if you defining your own dialect, it seems that all related logic has moved to `org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.LimitHandler` and `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect#getLimitHandler`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Hmmm I see. Thanks! However, how about the org.hibernate.engine.spi.RowSelection and the org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor? Anything for those?

Comment: `public String processSql(String sql, RowSelection selection)` - that is covered by `org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.LimitHandler` as I mentioned earlier. EmptyInterceptor was removed in favour of default methods in Interceptor.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Thank you! I will take a closer look.

Comment: Oh Lord... why break things this way ?

Comment: @MagnoC Yeah I am confused too...